# Touch drag a View all over the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UIImageView placed with frame (0,0,320,200).

i have added touch drag to it using simple gesture.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)set withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint p = [[set anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];
    self.center = p;
}
```

It works fine, however as soon as i drag it to bottom of screen let's say and remove my finger and then try to touch it, it stops detecting touch on the view and start detecting touch on the views on the screen. Now this imageView is placed on top of all views so i am not sure even its dragged why it doesn't get touches ,

Now if somehow using any button make it move ot its original position it starts detecting touch again.

So whats going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up a `gestureRecognizer` within your `viewDidLoad` method for example.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:)];

[YourImageView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

Once your ImageView has been moved the `gestureRecognizer` object will fire the target method you created `wasDragged:` and from within here you can update the view's position.

```
- (void)wasDragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

     UIImagewView *imageView = (UIImagewView *)recognizer.view;
     CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:imageView];

     imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + translation.x, imageView.center.y + translation.y);
     [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:imageView];
}
```

After this has been dragged to the bottom of the screen as you say, you should be able to drag it again from the position you last left it in.

I hope this helps.

Comment: why is the UIImageView ignoring touch after its center has been shifted outside of the UIView its been added?

Comment: You can just ignore that the default is YES anyway. I've edited the answer to remove it as you won't need to set this here. I used it as I had a specific set up where I was changing an image as it moved.